# How to call for method of an object that is in an arraylist collection?

Tags: java, c#

I was doing my lab hw. I have been trying to solve that problem for more than an hour
The polymorphism btw classes
Shape(Triangle + Rectangle)
Triangle(ScaleneTriangle, EquilateralTriangle, RightTriangle)
Rectangle(Square)

Java solution also will be fine for me.

```
    
            Triangle scalene = new ScaleneTriangle(3,4,5);
            Triangle equilateral= new EquilateralTriangle(3,3,3);
            Triangle right = new RightTriangle(3,4,5);
            Rectangle square = new Square(4);
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(2,5);
            
           List<Shape> shapes = new List<Shape>();
           //All the shapes are derived classes of Shape
            shapes.Add(equilateral);
            shapes.Add(right);
            shapes.Add(scalene);
            shapes.Add(rectangle);
            shapes.Add(square);
            foreach (var shape in shapes)
            {
                if (shape is Triangle)
                {
                    shape.        //I want to call the method of equilateral, right, scalene which are derived 
                                 //classes of Triangle

                }
                else if (shape is Rectangle)
                {
                    shape.    //I want to call the method of the rectangle(base) and square(derived)
                }
                    
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### C#

You probably want `as`:

```
            if (shape is Triangle)
            {
                (shape as Triangle).GetHypotenuseLength();        
                (shape as Triangle).GetSmallestCornerAngle();        
                (shape as Triangle).GetTypeOfTriangle();        
            }
```

You can make your life easier not having to `as` all the time:

```
            if (shape is Triangle t)
            {
                t.GetHypotenuseLength();        
                t.GetSmallestCornerAngle();        
                t.GetTypeOfTriangle();      
            }
```

Note that a lot of this is against polymorphism; the whole cool thing about polymorphing is that you don't write a bunch of code that is "if it's a triangle then.. if it's a square then..." because that code can only ever cope with the shapes it knows about at the time. If your mate adds a plugin that implements pentagon your code will flat out ignore it

The whole idea of polymorphism is that ALL your shapes can (because they descend from Shape which has a `DrawYourselfOnThisCanvasPlz(Canvas c)` method) is that each different shape knows how to draw itself on a canvas, so you can just:

```
foreach(Shape s in listOfShapes)
  s.DrawYourselfOnThisCanvasPlz(c);
```

Now your triangles and squares will draw themselves, and your mate's pentagon will draw itself if the user of your paint program has added pentagons into the list of shapes...

Aim to try and find ways of treating all these things *as generic shapes*, and **not** as particular instances of exact shapes that you know about right now.. Rather than `if triangle then call_those_triangle_methods` just have a `shape.PrintSomeInfoAboutYourselfToTheConsole()` and the square will say "hey, i'm a square and my sides are..." and the triangle says "i'm a triangle with angles of .. and a hypotenuse of ..."..

Comment: Thank you that worked just fine for me :)

Comment: No probs, added some more info for you

Comment: I just did it. I have been using this website for 3 years never asked a question :) That's why I am not familiar with this kind of things. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you can cast an object if you know its type:

```
if (shape instanceof Rectangle) {
    Rectangle rectangle = (Rectangle) shape;
    // whatever the method is called
    rectangle.getWidth()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast it to the Triangle or Rectangle before calling the method.  Here is the Java solution.

```
for (Shape shape : shapes) {
        if (shape instanceof Triangle) {
             ((Triangle)shape).call method(s) for triangle here
        } else if (shape instanceof Rectangle) {
             ((Rectangle)shape).call method(s) for Rectangle here
        }
}
```